# Yocto deploy Debug or Release prebuild?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am writing a bitbake recipe to deploy a third party pre-built tool, similar to this wiki page: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Packaging_Prebuilt_Libraries

However, I have a Release and Debug pre-build versions of the tool available as *.so files. How do I distinguish inside the recipe which one of both build types I shall deploy?

Thanks and regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

You can have two different virtual recipes each with their own `.so` file. This then warrants a selection in a configuration file (with `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/my-recipe`), so either in a machine or distro configuration file. This is probably preferred if you consider having release and debug distros.

A second option is to install the libraries in two different paths, in two different `PACKAGES` (use `FILES_my-package` for that) and make them `RCONFLICTS_my-package` each other to be sure they can't both be in the rootfs. After that, you could write a `pkg_postinst_my-package()` task specific to each package that actually move the library from the "different" path to the intended one. This will be run both at build time when creating the rootfs and at runtime on first boot, so you need to make sure to exclude one or the other (it's usually done by checking if `${D}` exists, which does at build time but not runtime).

c.f.: http://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/dev-manual-common-tasks.html#post-installation-scripts

If you can manage to have both libraries installed in your rootfs and select the one you want with the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, a simple recipe, with two packages with each library in a different location, will be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! Due to size constraints in the rootfs I will probably choose the first solution.

Comment: Actually, the first and second suggestions would work for you, just not the third :)